# Android: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released

Tags: google-maps, logcat, android-virtual-device

I am following the Google [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview) to learn MapsAPI integration in Android. I have followed it through to step 9 where I compile the first part of the project, unfortunately the launch fails (inside an AVD) and this is the error (red) part in LogCat.

```
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867):  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867):  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:133)
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867):  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867):  at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:219)
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867):  at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:204)
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:586)
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:7859)
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$1900(PackageManagerService.java:172)
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$5.run(PackageManagerService.java:5995)
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-01 22:17:16.088: E/StrictMode(867):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I can't make heads nor tail of the log, but the console reports:

```
[2013-07-02 01:05:11 - RemVoxMapView] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_CERTIFICATE_ENCODING
[2013-07-02 01:05:11 - RemVoxMapView] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-07-02 01:05:11 - RemVoxMapView] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Seemed to be an issue with the auth by Google, I had not added the SHA1 value for the APIv3 Android key on the Google console. The app now launches, but doesn't load any map tiles.